# Best way to store small amount of data

Tags: c#, winforms, data-storage

I'm new to windows app and I would like to know what the best way to save a small amount of data, like 1 value a day.

I'm going for the text file because it's easy, but I know i could use MS Access.

Do you have other option ? Faster or better ?

Comment: mbratch make me think of xml too ... is it a good option too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to read it then use a plain text file.

If you need to read the values back into the application then serialize to an XML or binary file by  [making your user data serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437604/c-sharp-storage-of-user-entered-data/437614#437614) possibly by having a *List* of values in your object.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are already considering using a MS Access database, I would recommend using SQLite.  Here's a quote from their site ([SQLite Home Page](http://www.sqlite.org/)):

> SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.

It is really very easy to use - no installations required, you simply need to reference a DLL.

Comment: this is the best answer because of that quoted message from sqlite

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to use the data? Do you just want to look at it once in awhile? Do you plan to analyze it in a spreadsheet? Etc. Based upon what you say so far, I would just use a text file, one value per line. Even if later you wanted to do more with it, it's easy to import into spreadsheets, etc. If the daily data is a little more complicated (maybe a couple of different values for things each day), you might consider something like YAML.

Comment: I would see look at it once in a while, but I'll check the YAML, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why stray from the path? XML gives you the ability to expand on it later without having to rethink everything.

Answer (score 0):

Its mainly dependent upon the complexity of the data that you want to store. If its just DateTime some other simple built in type you would be able to recreate that object as a strongly typed one easily. But in case if its more complicated I would suggest you to create a serializable class (link on how to create such class is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx)) and then use one of Binary or SOAP serializations based on the size, security and other such needs. I am suggesting this as it would be best to be able to recreate objects as strongly typed ones from a flat file rather than just trying to parse what's there in the flat file.

Please let me know in case you need more clarity.

Thanks,
Sai Pavan